# How to make a repeating multiple interval timer in Android?

Tags: android

I have searched through Google, SO and Android developers but I need some further help for decision making. This has been discussed in discrete subjects but I'd like to have a bit of help with insight/design-decisions.

What I'd like to accomplish is a kind of timer that plays an alarm after, say 45 minutes, and plays an alarm, say 15 minutes after that. When the last alarm has fired, the cycle restarts indefinitely. This would sequentially look like Start -> 45min countdown -> Alarm -> 15min countdown -> Alarm -> go back to 45min countdown to repeat cycle.

This is an attempt at constructing a Work/Break-cycle app but I'm having both specific problems as well as probable design-flaws.

My goal, in short:

- Create a Work/Break-cycle that fires alarms at specific intervals
- Make it survive phone-sleep (without necessarily forcing to have the screen on)
- Update the UI to get a feedback of progress for each interval/timer

Currently I'm (in general, there are a few specifics that differ) using a Service that implements a Runnable with a delay matching the duration of the different timers. When the first delay is up (after 45 minutes), another Runnable is initialized and run (set to 15 minutes).
This works pretty well. I make use of a partial wakelock for the Service and most of the times get this to run for about a cycle, but then things silently seem to stop. If I close the application and start it again, the cycle restarts.

Now, apart from this I'd like to update a UI with the amount of minutes left on each timer, which means I have to somehow, regularly, make "posts" to the UI in order to see a visual progress.

Am I going about this the right way? Should I have another approach on this and what would be a suitable one?

Comment: So it only ever runs once - 45 mins then 15 mins then nothing? (I hope you're testing it with seconds rather than minutes?)

Comment: AlarmManager#setRepeating(..), supply a triggerAtTime 45mins into the future and a 15 minute interval. To restore the alarm between reboots you're going to need a boot-completed broadcast receiver. If you're going to do heavy lifting for each trigger point, consider holding at least a partial wake-lock while doing your work.

Comment: @weston: Let me clarify. The cycle goes as: 45min -> 15min -> 45min -> 15min, repeating indefinitely.

Comment: @Jens: Setting a triggerAtTime on 45 and a 15 minute interval, wouldn't this mean the alarm fires at 15, 30 and 45?

Comment: triggerAtTime defines the first trigger time. Repeat interval all subsequent triggers, i.e. 45, 15, 15, 15, 15 ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `AlarmManager` to schedule alarms, passing in whatever `Intent` you'd like to occur at the the time you've scheduled the alarm for. When 45 minute alarm goes off, schedule another alarm and when that one goes off, schedule another 45 minute alarm, and so on.
**EDIT**

To update the UI each minute to tell how much time is left do something like this in your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
int minutes = 45;
TextView tv;
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
super.onCreate(state);
//set the content, grab your textview, etc...boilerplate
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    //schedule alarm here and post runnable as soon as scheduled
    handler.post(r)
}

    //somewhere else in your Class
     Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            if(!minutes == 0)
               tv.setText(minutes--);
               handler.postDelayed(this, 60000); //run the runnable in a minute again 
            else 
               handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: Alright, let's look into the AlarmManager for setting alarms. With the AlarmManager I can set the times for when the alarms go off but how do I update the UI each minute to tell how much time is left before an alarm goes off?

Comment: I'll try and experiment with this for a bit and see what I can come up with. Don't know if it will wake me there yet, I might have a couple of follow-ups while I'm meddling about.

Comment: Alright, I seem to be getting somewhere. I'm using a BroadcastReceiver to catch the first alarm, then I use this BroadcastReceiver to set the next alarm. Is this a suitable way to do things?
Is it possible to send data back to the Activity that called (set the alarm for) the BroadcastReceiver? That way I could reset counters and whatnot in the UI and use the Handler you suggested.

Comment: @LucuryMode: I managed to get the alarm handling to work consistently, as far as I can tell.
I am now creating and calling a BroadcastReceiver that schedules the alarms in the sequence 45min -> 15min -> repeat cycle starting with 45min. The alarm sound goes off and I can remove schedules as well as add new ones with Start and Stop buttons. What I have left is the countdown timers and I'll have a go at the handler you suggested.

Comment: I used two CountDownTimers to keep track of the counters. I'm having a bit of an issue with playing sounds though. At the moment I'm using a MediaPlayer within the BroadcastReceiver to play an alarm sound. The thing is, I'm creating new instances of MediaPlayer which in the end bites me because I don't release it when I'm done with it. I don't know how to solve this, it doesn't seem as if I can create a member variable containing a boolean to help me in not unnecessarily creating a bunch of MediaPlayers. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: @DrLaban accept the answer for this question and post a new question with the details of the mediaplayer problems you're having

Comment: You led me in the direction for this one and I've accepted your answer.