# How to repeat timer

Tags: java, android, timer

Hi how to repeat simple countdown timer a certain number of times. For example 5 times. I am making simple timer and I would like to repeat it 6 times after 2 seconds delay.

```
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv2.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Question

Please find link below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019377/how-to-make-a-repeating-multiple-interval-timer-in-android
```